# Analyzing the dependence of a sequence $(x_n)$ on its first term.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $f(x):=1/4+x-x^2$.  Define $x_n:=f(x_{n-1}), n\in \mathbb N$.

Define $S_t:=\{x_0\in \mathbb R: \lim x_n=t\}$ for $t\in \mathbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\}$.

The exercise is to find $S_t$ whenever $\lim x_n$ exists in $\mathbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\}$.

I did it as follows:

If $x_0=0$, then $x_1=f(x_0)=1/4>x_0$. Noting that $\max f(x)=1/2,$ it follows that the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded from above.  Since $x_{n+1}-x_n=(x_n-x_{n-1})(1-x_n-x_{n-1})$, it follows by Induction that the sequence $(x_n)$ is increasing. By monotone convergence theorem, $\lim x_n:=l$ is finite. It follows that $l=f(l)$ by continuity of $f$ and this gives $l^2=1/4$, whence $l=1/2$.  It follows that $0\in S_{1/2}$.

Remark: It is to be noted that if $\lim x_n$ is finite then it is either $1/2$ or $-1/2$.

$x_1=f(x_0)\implies x_1-x_0=(1/2-x_0)(1/2+x_0)\ge 0\iff x_0\in [-1/2, 1/2].$ Using the same ideas as above, it follows that the sequence $(x_n)$ is monotonically increasing. It follows that $(-1/2, 1/2]\subset S_{1/2}.\tag 1$

It is to be noted that if $\lim x_n$ is finite then it is either $1/2$ or $-1/2$.

$x_1-x_0\lt 0\iff x_0>1/2$ or $x_0<-1/2$.

Case $1):$ $x_0<-1/2$

$\implies x_1<x_0$ and $1-x_0-x_1>0$. From $x_{n+1}-x_n=(x_n-x_{n-1})(1-x_n-x_{n-1})$, it follows that $(x_n)$ is monotonically decreasing. $\lim x_n\le x_1<-1/2$, it follows that $\lim x_n=-\infty$. So $(-\infty, -1/2)\subset S_{-\infty}$.

Case $2): x_0>1/2$

Noting that $1-x_0-x_1\ge 0\iff x_0\ge 3/2$ or $x_0\le 1/2$, there are following cases:

Case $2a): 1-x_0-x_1\lt 0$

$\implies  x_0\in (1/2,3/2)$.

$x_2-x_1=(x_1-x_0)(1-x_0-x_1)\gt 0, x_3-x_2\gt 0$ and by induction it follows that $(x_n)$ is eventually monotonically increasing sequence and since $x_n\le 1/2$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, it follows that $\lim x_n$ is finite and by the remark above $\lim x_n=1/2$. It follows that $(-1/2,3/2)\subset S_{1/2}. \tag 2$

Case $2b):1-x_0-x_1\gt 0$ (the case when $1-x_0-x_1=0$ is easy and results in $3/2\in S_{-1/2}$)

$\implies x_0\gt 3/2$.

$1-x_1\gt 3/2\implies x_1\lt -1/2$. By induction, $(x_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence and by case $1): \lim x_n=-\infty$. It follows that $(3/2,\infty)\subset S_{-\infty}$.

It is concluded that $S_{1/2}=(-1/2, 3/2), S_{-1/2}=\{-1/2, 3/2\}$ and $S_{-\infty}=(3/2,\infty)$.

But the book's solution starts as follows:

$f(x)\le x$ for all $x\le -1/2$ and $f(x)<-1/2$ for all $x\ge 3/2$. So the sequence diverges both for $x\le -1/2$ and for $x\ge 3/2$.  Then the solution shows that if $x_0\in (-1/2,3/2)$ then $|x_{n+1}-1/2|<|x_0-1/2|^n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ so $(x_n)$ converges to $1/2$ in this case.

But this looks like some typo as clearly the sequence converges when $x_0=-1/2$ or $3/2$. Apart from that, I think that this solution is very fast but I don't understand **how the conclusion of divergence was made in the book from $f(x)\le x$.**

My solution above seems very lengthy so I want to know

1. if there are any general methods to analyze dependence of a sequence $(y_n)$ on the first term $y_1$ of the sequence.
2. if my solution is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Let solve inequality $f(x) < x$, then $x\in(-\infty;-\frac{1}{2})\cup(\frac{1}{2};+\infty)$. Accordingly $f(x) > x$ at $x \in (-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2})$. This can simplify consideration and we can say that limit is equal $-\infty$ for $x_0\in(-\infty;-\frac{1}{2})\cup(\frac{3}{2};+\infty)$, equal $-\frac{1}{2}$ for $x_0\in\{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\}$, and is equal $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x_0\in(-\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2})$.

Comment: Appendix to previous comment: if $x_0 > \frac{3}{2}$ or $x_0 < -\frac{1}{2}$ then $x_1 < -\frac{1}{2}$ and sequence is decreasing. Then limit is $-\infty$. If $x_0 \in (-\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2})$, then $-\frac{1}{2} < x_1 \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and sequence is either increasing or constant starting from $x_1$ and limit is $\frac{1}{2}$. If $x_0 \in \{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\}$ then $x_1=-\frac{1}{2}$ and sequence is constant starting from $x_1$ and limit is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Solution in the book has typo.